# Is it more secure to use PDO class InDirectly?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I an new to object oriented PHP. In tutorials , the instructor not using the PDO class directly , instead using it via function, like this

```
class Database{
  private $pdo;
  private $stmt;
  public function __construct(){$this->pdo = new PDO(blaa..blaa..);}
  public function preparequery($query){$this->stmt=$this->pdo->prepare($query);}
  public function bind($param,$value){$this->stmt->bindValue($param,$value);}
  public function execute(){$this->stmt->execute();}
  public function Fetch(){$this->stmt->fetchall();}
}
```

And then he call these public function for any database query like

```
$mysql = new Database;
$mysql->preparequery("INSERT INTO test(name,city) VALUES (:name,:city)");
$mysql->bind(':name',$_GET['name']);
$mysql->bind(':city',$_GET['city']);
$mysql->execute();
```

I understand it, but we can directly create a PDO object  and interact with database, So i just want to ask , Does above method provide some benifits(like more security or something) Or just it is used for make it simple(although I don't find it simple).

Comment: No. What has your class wrapper added..... nothing

Comment: Yes you can use PDO object directly but when PDO library make some changes you need to change you code in each file where you have used direct PDO object. So these Class makes you easy and fast when some changes made by PDO in future.

Comment: @RiggsFolly still unclear for me, can you please explain little more

Comment: @beginner RiggsFolly was simply saying that a class is not going to add any security, versus having the PDO object referenced outside of a class. A class adds no security, by itself. However, SCC was correct in saying that by having a class, your code will then reference that class whenever a DB connection is required. As a result, you have a single class to edit (versus finding every direct connection that you established). OOP allows you to use objects like classes, so that you don't repeat yourself later on. :)

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes

Comment: @SCC Nonsense. If it were possible to abstract over an API change with such a thin wrapper class, then there would be no need for them to make such an API change in the first place. A severe change that necessitated changes to how people used the PDO API would also necessitate altering use of the wrapper class's API. This wrapper class, as written, achieves absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 2):

*More secured* is **NOT** the point, but *more convenient*.

> Making use of the [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) (data modeling; methods, class, inheritance, etc.) concept as in seen in **PDO** helps ease and accelerate future edits as it makes one code [dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
>
> *[See suggested reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Object-oriented_programming)*

It will help you structure effectively and write less.

***Please note: OOP as mentioned above strictly refers to its concept; not the use of any given wrapper class.***

***PDO is PHP's approach to OOP***.

Comment: Beat me to the punch by a few seconds! :p He is absolutely correct. Upvoted.

Comment: PDO already has a Object model. Why wrap another over the top https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I'm simply referring to **OOP** in itself as elaborated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Object-oriented_programming), relating to PHP.

Comment: Edited my answer for clarify based on @RiggsFolly's question.

Comment: @nyedidikeke So this is not a bad practice ., should i use this method in my coding?

Comment: **OOP**, here, ***PHP Object-oriented Programming (PDO)***, is not a bad practice on the contrary, particularly when well implemented. It saves you not only time but makes you more productive.

Comment: @beginner I wouldn't do this with PDO in most cases. We see these PDO wrapper classes all over Stack Overflow each day, but rarely do they add functionality. Mostly they are used to abstract prepare()/execute() calls and the only time I consider that helpful is if SQL statements are expected to have narrowly varying structures.  The `Fetch()` method here which just calls `fetchAll()` for example, is superfluous and the `execute()` method which just calls `$stmt->execute()` is even more superfluous.

Comment: In many cases, the PDO wrapper classes we see have been built because older code had a similar wrapper class for the `mysql_*()` functions, which had no OO API, and could sometimes benefit from one. PDO already has a good one.

Comment: If you plan to support more APIs than just PDO (like mysqli for example), then using a thin wrapper class like this can serve as an adapter to expose the same functions for both classes. That's a good use case.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  Thanks , I also prefer to use PDO class Directly,Instead of wrapping them into another class.  But in tutorials , instructor using this method, So i thought this method must have some big benifits, but now i am assured , and I will use PDO Class directly. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I did stated in the comment trail above here, just us re-updating my answer to stress on the fact that when I made reference to **OOP**, I wasn't referring to any wrapper class but to the OOP concept as adopted in [PDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Object-oriented_programming). Your intervention seem to neglect that as in: misinterpreting my answer. **PDO is PHP's approach to OOP**.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yeah i understand,In OOP Their may be many cases where i should wrapp classes, but this is not  always convenient .(like.for PDO class)

Comment: Even though @MichaelBerkowski may have valid point(s), suggestive to his experience and opinion based (as it can generate a whole debate), my answer is tailored towards answering the question *(Is it more secure to use PDO class InDirectly? as well as intended purpose conveyed in the post)*. **Why downvote me for personal reasons which are highly out of the scopes of the question asked and answered?**

Comment: @nyedidikeke My comments here were not really directed at your answer (and I didn't vote) but toward the OP's "is this a bad practice" question.

Comment: Noted @MichaelBerkowski, but **not indicating that** (when commenting on my answer) **really made it** look so as ***comments*** (below a given post) are expected to be mediums of ***discussion relating to question(s) and or answer(s), for clarity, concerns, among others***.